# How to filter out objects from Django Rest serializer based on Foreign key set criteria

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and this is where I got stuck.

I have 3 models, as follows.

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    ...
    is_valid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    importance = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)


class StoreCategory(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

for the rest framework these are the serializers that I have:

```
class StoreCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    store = StoreSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = StoreCategory
        fields = ('store', )

class AllStoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # stores = StoreCategorySerializer(source="storecategory_set", many=True)
    stores = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_stores_list')

    def get_stores_list(self, obj):
        scs = obj.storecategory_set.exclude(store__is_valid=0).order_by('store__id')
        serializer = StoreCategorySerializer(scs, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'category', 'stores')
```

View is as follows:

```
class AllStores(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        categories = Category.objects.all().order_by('-importance')
        serializer = AllStoreSerializer(categories, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now, the problem is, I want to return categories for which there are stores with is_valid != 0. i.e. if the stores list for a category has 0 elements, then that category is not included in the data returned(data returned by the API). So basically id the storecategory_set has size equal to 0, then do not include that category.
How can I do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: What does your view look like? That appears to be missing from your question.

Comment: kevin is right, the view is where this query should take place. this is missing

Comment: @KevinBrown Just added the view details.

Comment: @KevinBrown please have a look.